# Merge 2D arrays on 3 same values

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2D arrays

```
$array1=[["a1", "a2", "h3", "a4"],["b1", "b2", "l3", "b4"], ["c1", "c2", "o3", "c4"],["d1", "d2", "k3", "d4"]];

$array1=[["b1", "b2", "l3", "b4"], ["a1", "a2", "h3", "a4"], ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"], ["c1", "c2", "t3", "c4"]];



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a1
            [1] => a2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => h3
                    [1] => h3
                )

            [3] => a4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b1
            [1] => b2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => l3
                    [1] => l3
                )

            [3] => b4
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c1
            [1] => c2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => o3
                    [1] => t3
                )

            [3] => c4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => d1
            [1] => d2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => k3
                    [1] => d3
                )

            [3] => d4
        )

)
```

> [[a1, a2, a3, a4],[b1, b2, b3, b4]]
>
> [[a1, a2, d3, a4],[b1, b2, e3, b4]]

and I want them to merge so finial array will be

> [[a1, a2, [a3,d3], a4],[b1, b2, [b3,e3], b4]]

So far I came up with this, but it look quite messy to me, is there any other solution how to merge 2D array on 3 same values ?

```
 $newArr = [];
  foreach($firstArray as $fArray){
   foreach($secondArray as $sArray){
        if($fArray['first_item'] === $sArray['first_item'] &&
           $fArray['second_item'] === $sArray['second_item'] &&
           $fArray['fourth_item'] === $sArray['fourth_item']){
             $newArr[] = [$farray['first_item'], $fArray['second_item],
             [$fArray['third_item'], $sArray['third_item']], $fArray['fourth_item]]
          }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your current code to get the desired output. I have changed the indexes which you are currently using in your post.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/804258)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$firstArray = [["a1", "a2", "h3", "a4"],["b1", "b2", "l3", "b4"], ["c1", "c2", "o3", "c4"],["d1", "d2", "k3", "d4"]];

$secondArray = [["b1", "b2", "l3", "b4"], ["a1", "a2", "h3", "a4"], ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"], ["c1", "c2", "t3", "c4"]];
$result = array();
$newArr = [];
foreach ($firstArray as $fArray)
{
    foreach ($secondArray as $sArray)
    {
        if ($fArray[0] === $sArray[0] && $fArray[1] === $sArray[1] && $fArray[3] === $sArray[3])
        {
            $newArr[] = [$fArray[0], $fArray[1],
             [$fArray[2], $sArray[2]], $fArray[3]];
        }
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a1
            [1] => a2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => h3
                    [1] => h3
                )

            [3] => a4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b1
            [1] => b2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => l3
                    [1] => l3
                )

            [3] => b4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c1
            [1] => c2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => o3
                    [1] => t3
                )

            [3] => c4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => d1
            [1] => d2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => k3
                    [1] => d3
                )

            [3] => d4
        )

)
```

Comment: It isn't quite what I need. Because for example I need to match first item of first Array to any other item that will have same first,second,fourth value. There will be only one case that item will match item. Your solution is good, be it works only when items are on same index.

Comment: @jemcaj Can you share your actual array on which you want to perform operation , so that it will be helpful

Comment: I edited OP with bigger array that has equal structure to my array.

Comment: @jemcaj Can you also share expected output for this also.

Comment: @jemcaj I am updating my post for this as well.., You can also try it here https://eval.in/804258

Comment: It's basically same as in op, but I think It's least complicated solution.